# What is the "&=" operator and why does Twilio use it when comparing strings?

Tags: python, operators, twilio

What is `&=` in python?

For example:

```
for c1, c2 in izip(string1, string2):
    result &= c1 == c2
```

I found it in the twilio python library:
https://github.com/twilio/twilio-python/blob/master/twilio/util.py#L62

Why don't they just compare the strings directly `return string1 == string2` and compare each character?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See the [secure_compare](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-python/blob/master/twilio/util.py#L62) doctring:

> Compare two strings while protecting against [Timing Attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timing_attack)

By *forcing* evaluation of every character an attacker can't use the time it took to guess where the difference occurred - with a "normal" implementation that returned immediately on the first difference, this would be possible.

The semantic counter to `result &= c1 == c2` (succeed when they are all the same) is actually `return c1 != c2` (fail/abort on the first difference), and not the proposed condition the question.

Now, `result &= c1 == c2` is the same as `result = result & (c1 == c2)`, where `&` (also known as a bitwsie-AND) is a *strict* logical-AND over Booleans. This means that the use of the result accumulator will remain True *if and only if* the result was previously True and the compassion is also True.

Comment: I honestly would be interested in the assembly that's produced, the way it's set up looks like it could reduce into semi-atomic functions per for loop.  Which would help further keep the action thread-safe secure.

Comment: It still makes it down into compiled at some point.  So it's still a viable reason to think on.

Comment: @JeffLangemeier: Since strings are immutable, there's no thread safety issue in the first place.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy That's more of what I was trying to figure out through that.